# Como definir data padrão para campos do tipo DATE e TIME

Tags: jquery, html, html5

No *modal* seguinte que contém dois campos do tipo `date`, "De: `dd/mm/aaaa` e Até: `dd/mm/aaaa`" quero definir a data "De" para a data atual, "Até" para um dia de diferença e no campo `time` definir uma hora padrão.

Campos do tipo *Date*:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="data-inicio-excecao"> Data * </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="data-inicio-excecao" name="data-inicio-excecao" tabindex="2" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="data-termino-excecao"> Até </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="data-termino-excecao" name="data-termino-excecao" tabindex="3" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Campos do tipo *Time*:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="hora-inicio-excecao"> Hora Início * </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora-inicio-excecao" name="hora-inicio-excecao" tabindex="4" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="hora-termino-excecao"> Até </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora-termino-excecao" name="hora-termino-excecao" tabindex="5" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como posso fazer isso utilizando JQuery?

Comment: O que você já fez? Posta o código ai pra facilitar que te ajudem.

Comment: Só utilizar new Date().toLocaleString() e colocar o value dentro dos seus inputs.

Comment: pode me dar um exemplo Paulo?

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta com as datas. Para a hora, explique melhor o que precisa, que edito a resposta.

Comment: Preciso que quando a modal abrir, a Hora Início seja 8:00 e a Hora Até seja 18:00, por padrão. Sendo possível alterar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Para as suas datas, você pode utilizar a função [Date()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) que é uma característica do JavaScript.

Assim, você seleciona a data atual e adiciona os valores no respectivos campos.
Seu código ficaria assim:

```html
 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var dt = new Date();//Instancia a data
 var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();//hora
    var diaAtual = dt.getDate() + "/" + (dt.getMonth()+1) + "/" + dt.getFullYear();//Dia atual concatenado
      var diaAte = (dt.getDate()+1) + "/" + (dt.getMonth()+1) + "/" + dt.getFullYear();//dia +1 concatenado
    $('#data-inicio-excecao').val(diaAtual); //Atribui o valor do dia atual
    $('#data-termino-excecao').val(diaAte); //Atribui o valor do dia +1
    console.log(day);
});
});//]]> 

</script>

<style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body>
  <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="data-inicio-excecao"> Data * </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data-inicio-excecao" name="data-inicio-excecao" tabindex="2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="data-termino-excecao"> Até </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data-termino-excecao" name="data-termino-excecao" tabindex="3">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, isso ajudou!